# cannot install python3-libnvinfer on ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, nvidia, tensorrt

Hi I want to install python3-libnvinfer and python3-libnvinfer-dev package on Ubuntu20.04 with python3.8
my goal is install TensorRT-8 on ubuntu 20.04
I do the exact installaion steps on nvidia site.
bu when I try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer
```

I'll get this Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-libnvinfer : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also try this with Python3.7 and don't fix...

I Can't Install Python3.10 because seems not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried installing TensorRT on Ubuntu 20.04 and I expect it to install correctly with python 3.8 and also with Python3.7
I Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinvfer
```

but I ran into an Error described above.

Comment: Please try again using this command `sudo aptitude install python3-libnvinfer-dev` to install python3-libnvinfer in your system. You can refer to this [doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) for more details which might be helpful.

Comment: @TFer2 Thanks for your help, why was this error caused? this command should work with apt-get but it doesn't...